# In Portugal and Brazil, are indirect requests considered polite?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, cultura, cortesia

The phrase "please do the needful" in Indian English [can come across as rude](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/17621/9346) to American English speakers, possibly because [it's an indirect, rather than direct request.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/61233/9346) It's apparently considered polite in India, however.

In the Portuguese of Portugal and Brazil, would an indirect request like

> Não tenho o seu documento. Por favor, resolva isso.

be considered polite or rude? Would something more direct like

> Não tenho o seu documento. Por favor, me envie uma cópia.

be considered better or worse?

Answer (score 3):

Let's translate the phrases to English:

> I don't have your document. Please, solve that.

> I don't have your document. Please, send me a copy.

First, which one is or is not rude (or even both or none of them) heavily depends on their context.

However, being contextless or imagining some typical likely context for that, I think that even in English the first form is more likely to be unfriendly than the second. I don't think that "rude" is the best word for that, "unfriendly" seems to be a better fit.

Anyway, the "unfriendlyness" seems to be carried over between the translation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second one is better. The first one seems like the orator made a mistake and is now mandating that I fix it, which is rather rude. The second one sounds more like "I made a mistake; can you help me fix it?"; even though the orator is still asking that I do it, he is not enforcing it.

Even if the orator as in fact not made any mistake, but I have, it is just rude to demand that I do it.

Comment: Is this only because I used "resolver"? Would another word (maybe "tratar"?) change that?

Comment: Nah, I don't think so; I think it holds in general